# Поиск трёхзначных чисел в массиве чисел

Tags: pascal

Помогите пожалуйста. У меня имеется массив из чисел от 0 до 1000.Как найти трехзначное число на паскале?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Делаем цикл по всему массиву чисел
- Проверяем внутри каждого цикла, оно трехзначное или нет.

Чтобы проверить оно трехзначное или нет, надо чтобы оно было от 100 до 999, т.е. проверить чтобы оно было больше и равно 100 и меньше и равно 999.